Accessing namespaces via iterators/pointers?
I am currently facing a design/language problem of sorts. I have 3 files, A,B,and C which have their own namespaces defined as A,B,and C respectively. Each namespace has exactly the same function signatures, only implemented differently (think a REST API call with different but similar APIs).
Now my aim is to be able to call these functions from the correct namespace without repeating the function name.
Ideally I'd like to do something like this:
#include <iostream>

#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"

enum ns {
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2
};
int main() {

    auto NS = {A, B, C}; //these are the namespaces

    if (condition){
        int n = get_index();
        NS[n]::myfunc();
    }
}

where myfunc() is defined, albeit differently, in each source file corresponding to A.h, B.h, and C.h.
Can someone tell me whether there is a way to do this, or suggest an alternate design pattern I should adopt? Thanks
To explain my problem more concretely, I have a DataReader class which fetches data about say cars, from REST endpoints by vendors A, B, C and preprocesses them. I did think of making a class and subclassing them for different vendors, but then won't it be too complicated, having a vendor-specific class inside my DataReader class?

You can define a base class with a virtual method myfunc() with the 3 class A,B and C deriving from it and implementing myfunc().

I did think of it, but in this case the semantics of making another class seem weird to me. I have edited the question to make my problem more clear.

I don't see how your edit changes the issue. Posted a complete answer.

Why not void(*func)() = get_myfunc(); and then just call func()?

@TedLyngmo that's a valid approach. But I thought that if the real case is more complicated with several methods using a class hierarchy might be proper as well.

"won't it be too complicated"  That's a matter of opinion, but an interface base class is the traditional method for establishing an interface that could have different implementations.

@wohlstad You are probably correct. The question does feel a bit oversimplified.

Namespaces affect compile time name lookup. You have runtime input, so a compile time decision is too early.

You can create a base class/struct with a pure-virtual method myfunc(),
and then make A,B and C (each can reside in its namespace if you want them to, but it's not a must) derive from it and implement myfunc.
You can then store them all in an array, and use a polymorphic call the invoke the proper method based on an index:
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void myfunc() = 0;
};

namespace AAA   // using a namespace is optional
{
    struct A : public Base {
        void myfunc() override { std::cout << "A::myfunc()\n"; }
    };
}

namespace BBB   // using a namespace is optional
{
    struct B : public Base {
        void myfunc() override { std::cout << "B::myfunc()\n"; }
    };
}

namespace CCC   // using a namespace is optional
{
    struct C : public Base {
        void myfunc() override { std::cout << "C::myfunc()\n"; }
    };
}

int main() {
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<Base>, 3> objs = {
        std::make_unique<AAA::A>(),
        std::make_unique<BBB::B>(),
        std::make_unique<CCC::C>()
    };

    objs[0]->myfunc();
    objs[1]->myfunc();
    objs[2]->myfunc();
}

Output:
A::myfunc()
B::myfunc()
C::myfunc()

Live demo.
Notes:

The only reason I used structs instead of classes is to make the demo a few lines shorter (save the public: lines). You can use classes of course instead of them.
I added the namespaces just in case you would like to put your classes in ones (since you mentioned them in the question), although they are not really needed for the solution above.


That looks cool, despite my initial hesitation. I'll do this thanks

Happy to help @insipidintegrator. As you can see in one of the comments below your question, using inheritance and virtual methods is the traditional approach to solve such a problem in C++.

By the way, any reason you chose struct? From what I know they are exactly same except the default access specifiers (struct is public and class is private)

It's perhaps worth noting that the namespaces were proposed in the question as part of the solution, but they are no longer necessary in this solution.

@insipidintegrator The only reason is to make the demo a few lines shorter (to save the public lines). You can use a class of course. Editted and added a note about it.

@DrewDormann yes I was not sure about them. Considred to remove them but thought maybe the OP would like to use them anyway. Editted to add a note about it.

You can use an array of function pointers (or std::function) to invoke the appropriate function via an enum.
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

namespace NSA {
int my_func(int x, int y) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    return x + y;
}
}
namespace NSB {
int my_func(int x, int y) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    return x - y;
}
}
namespace NSC {
int my_func(int x, int y) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    return x * y;
}
}

enum ns {
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2
};

constexpr std::array funcs = {&NSA::my_func, &NSB::my_func, &NSC::my_func};

int main()
{
    return funcs[ns::A](10, 20);
}

If you're open to using macros, they can be used to avoid repeating tokens in the code.  Here is an example:
#define PPCAT_NX(A, B) A ## B
#define PPCAT(A, B) PPCAT_NX(A, B)
#define DEFINE_FUNC_ARRAY(FN) constexpr std::array PPCAT(invoke_, FN) = { &NSA::FN, &NSB::FN, &NSC::FN };

DEFINE_FUNC_ARRAY(my_func)

int main()
{
    return invoke_my_func[ns::A](10, 20);
}


Yes I did do it like this initially, but asked here since I didn't like repeating the my_func part so many times in the array funcs. I wanted to get some advantage from the fact that I used exactly the same function signature in every namespace. I'll do it using classes, but +1 for introducing me to __PRETTY_FUNCTION__!

@insipidintegrator, there is no way in C++ to achieve the syntax you "want" in the original question.  Also, if you have multiple functions, then a class hierarchy (described in the other answer) is almost certainly your best option.

@insipidintegrator, token repetition can be reduced via macros.  Note: I'm not trying to change your mind to use this approach. =)

If you can turn namespaces into "static" classes, you can then use template:
#include <variant>

enum ns {
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2
};
std::variant<
    std::type_identity<A>,
    std::type_identity<B>,
    std::type_identity<C>>
to_variant(ns e)
{
    switch (e) {
        case ns::A: return std::type_identity<A>{};
        case ns::B: return std::type_identity<B>{};
        case ns::C: return std::type_identity<C>{};
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("no valid enum ns");
}

int main() {
    ns n = get_index();
    std::visit([]<class T>(std::type_identity<T>){ T::myfunc(); }, to_variant(n));
}

Demo
